# How to copy file from s3 bucket to a folder in same s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying a simple operation within a python lambda that just copies a file on upload to a specific folder within that *same* s3 bucket, but Im running into issues. If I hardcode the file, this works but if I try to pass in the src_key of the file, then I get an infinite loop on the folder im wanting to transfer the file(s) to.

Here is my lambda for this thus far.

```
import os
import logging
import boto3


DST_BUCKET = os.environ.get('DST_BUCKET')
REGION = os.environ.get('REGION')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=REGION)

def handler(event, context):
    LOGGER.info(f'Event structure: {event}')
    LOGGER.info(f'DST_BUCKET: {DST_BUCKET}')

    for record in event['Records']:
        src_bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        copy_source = {
                    'Bucket': src_bucket,
                    'Key': src_key
                        }
        bucket = s3.Bucket(DST_BUCKET)
        bucket.copy(copy_source, src_key)

        try:
            #Check file
            s3.Object(DST_BUCKET, src_key).load()
            LOGGER.info(f"File {src_key} uploaded to Bucket {DST_BUCKET}")

            # had to hardcode bucket name here
            src_bucket2 = s3.Bucket('send-bucket01')

            # this is key bit with src_key (NOTE: This is pre-created folder in s3 bucket)
            src_bucket2.copy(copy_source, 'fileProcessed/' + src_key)
    
        except Exception as e:
            return {"error":str(e)}

    return {'status': 'ok'}
```

The key line is....

`src_bucket2.copy(copy_source, 'fileProcessed/' + src_key)`

I was thinking this would work, but this just continually copies the folder name and file over and over again in the fileProcessed folder.

Again, if I hardcode the actual file this works (i.e, 'fileProcessed/myfile.pdf), however, I want to make this dynamic to accept any file uploaded to be put in the fileProcessd folder.

Note: I’ve got a requirement to copy these files from the root path of the s3 bucket not from a precreated folder which I could set the folder prefix in the copy event.

Comment: dispose of any notion of "Folders".  S3 only has object prefixes which often look like folders but are merely object names.   The web console makes this confusing by allowing empty "folders" to appear if you create an object name ending in / but this is in reality an empty object, not a folder.  You never need to create a "folder" in S3 unless you want it to show up in the web console when it's empty.

Comment: `except Exception as e:            return {"error":str(e)}` Recommend you not catch exceptions and let them be handled automatically.  You may well find some challenges to your assumptions  reading through the traceback

Comment: @erik258 thanks for the insight. So what I've noticed now is that when I include this, `src_bucket2.copy(copy_source, 'fileProcessed/src_key')`, this doesnt loop which is good, and if I download the file in s3, its the correct file, but its named "src_key". Is there a way to retain the original filename? I think that's all I need, and then will update the exception block based on your comments.

Comment: Do you just mean `'fileProcessed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1]` ?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your AWS Lambda function is configured to be **triggered by the creation of an object** in Amazon S3. Therefore, the reason why it "continually copies the folder name and file over and over again" is because the copied object is **again triggering the Lambda function**.

To prevent this happening, ensure that the Event configuration in the S3 bucket **only triggers on a specific path (folder)** rather than triggering on the bucket as a whole. For example, you might have an `incoming/` path.

Then, when the Lambda function copies it to the `fileProcessed/` path, it will **not** trigger the event again (because the event only triggers on the `incoming/` path).

Comment: Makes sense but I have requirement to copy everything from the root/base path of the bucket so I don’t think that will work. If that were not the case then that would be easy.

Answer (score -1):

Props to @AnonCoward in above comments for answering my use case. If anyone else is figuring this out, the following worked for me:

`src_bucket2.copy(copy_source, 'fileProcessed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1])`

As stated above I’ve got a requirement to copy these files from the root path of the source s3 bucket not from a pre created folder. If you can copy files from a given folder then just set the folder path in the event configuration of the s3 bucket which is simple.

Comment: This works because I have a requirement to copy the files in the root path of the s3 bucket not from one folder to another folder/directory.

Comment: If your S3 Event has been configured to trigger on the root of the bucket, then the above code will _not_ prevent the event from firing after the copy. It is simply copying the same file to itself infinitely, so you don't notice it. Take a look at the Lambda function's metrics to see how many times it is being triggered, and check CloudWatch Logs to make sure it isn't being repeatedly executed.

Comment: I think you're right, even with 'src_bucket2.copy(copy_source, 'fileProcessed/' + src_key.split('/')[-1])' its still doing infinite loop. How do I make it to only do one file at a time?

Comment: There are two options: (1) Have separate path for 'incoming' and 'processed' objects. Configure the trigger to only fire for the 'incoming' path (as per my Answer); (2) Add an `if` statement to the beginning of the Lambda function. It should examine the path of the `key` that is passed into the function. It should only copy the object is there is no `/` in the `key` (which indicates the object is in the root of the bucket): `if '/' not in key: copy_object()`

Comment: I went with option 1. If there are various folders that need to be copied to "processed" after the "incoming" is triggered to the other bucket, do you know how to do that? Basically the prefix of the event is set to /incoming so it will copy all those, but I also have various folders in that /incoming folder that I would be copied over to "processed" as well, not just individual files; there are folders and files within those folders. Insight appreciated.

Comment: If a trigger has been configured on a prefix of `incoming/`, then it will also fire on subfolders (eg `incoming/foo/`). Please note that the trigger uses a **prefix**, which means the _start of the object Key_ -- this is not a 'folder' (since folders do not exist in Amazon S3). Any object that has a key starting with `incoming/` will cause the trigger to fire. Object keys (filenames) include the **full path** of the object.